Edit material without applying to the current object
When an object is selected , I can edit its material nodes in shader editor. What if I want to edit other material in the shader editor ? if I select the other material from dropdown list, it will automatically apply to current object. I just want to switch to other material and modify it without have to select the object first.
let say I want to paste my custom nodes to 10 different material without have to deal with selecting the placeholder object first. How can I switch between shader/material faster ?
Any solution ?

I don't think there is a way. The most simple solution would be to add another material slot (not at first place). The first material will be the one apply to your object, all others aren't used by default. Does it solve your question ?

Thanks, That's what I did and found it's not a fast workflow. I created a dummy object and apply all those 10 materials on that dummy. so it will appears on 10 slots so I can switch from the dropdown without to worry about the dummy . It's just I don't like the additional steps.

You can use only 1 additionnal slot and change which material it uses, which means 2 clicks when you want to change material.
